# What happens to the data when uploading it to gcp bigquery when there is no internet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using `GCP Bigquery` to store some data. I have created a `pub/sub` job for the `Dataflow` of the event.Currently, I am facing a issue with data loss. Sometimes, due to **"no internet connection"** the data is not uploaded to bigquery and the data for that time duration is lost. How can i overcome this situation.

Or what kind of database should i use to store data offline and then upload it online whenever there is connectivity.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to have is either a retry mechanism or a persistent storage. There can be several ways to implement this.

You can use a Message Queue to store data and process. Choice of message queue can be either cloud based like AWS SQS, Cloud Pub/Sub(GCP) or a hosted one like Kafka, RabbitMq.

Another but a bit unoptimized way could be to persist data locally till it is successfully uploaded on the cloud. Local storage can be either some buffer or database etc. If upload is failed you, retry again from the storage. This is something similar to Producer Consumer Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Google Compute Engine` to store your data and always run your data loading job from there. In that case, if your internet connection is lost, data will still continue to load into BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

By what I understood you are publishing data to `PubSub` and `Dataflow` does the rest to get the data inside BigQuery, is it right?

The options I suggest to you:

1. If your connection loss happens occasionally and for a short amount of time, a **retry mechanism** could be enough to solve this problem.
2. If you have frequent connection loss or connection loss for large periods of time, I suggest that you mix a retry mechanism with some **process redundancy**. You could for example have two process running in different machines to  avoid this kind of situation. Its important to mention that for this case you could also try only a retry mechanism but it would be more complex because you would need to determine if the process failed, save the data somewhere (if its not saved) and trigger the process again in the future.
3. I suggest that you take a look in [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/). Its a very powerful data flow automation software that might help you solving this kind of issue. Apache Nifi has specific processors to push data directly to PubSub.
4. As a last suggestion, you could create an automated process to make **data quality** analysis after the data ingestion. Having this process you could determine more easily if your process failed.